# Is it possible to require at least one field from a set of defined fields?

Tags: javascript, joi

Given a definition like this:

```
const querySchema = joi.object({
  one: joi.string().min(1).max(255),
  two: joi.string().min(1).max(255),
  three: joi.string().min(1).max(255),
});
```

Is there a way to require **at least one** of those fields? I don't care which one.

**Note**: the solution provided for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864812/using-joi-require-one-of-two-fields-to-be-non-empty) doesn't serve me as I have 7 fields and they may grow, so doing all the possible combinations is a no-go.

Couldn't find any methods in [Joi API Reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.3.1/API.md) that may be useful for this use case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you *really* don't care which one is required then you could just ensure there is at least one key in the object by using [`object().min(1)`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectminlimit).

```
const querySchema = joi.object({
    one: joi.string().min(1).max(255),
    two: joi.string().min(1).max(255),
    three: joi.string().min(1).max(255),
}).min(1);
```

At least one key (`one`, `two`, `three`) must be required. Keys with names different to those three will be rejected.

Answer (score 32):

Found another way to do it besides the one suggested by @Ankh, was in [documentation](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectorpeers-options) but I couldn't find it before:

```
const schema = joi.object({
   a: joi.number(),
   b: joi.number(),
}).or('a', 'b');
```

This method is good if one needs to require a specific set of keys, while @Ankh's is better when the requirement is exaclty as I this question title and you have many keys, so I'm choosing his answer over mine as the right one.

Just wanted to leave here another way to do it.