# Require at least one non-null child in joi object that allows null

Tags: validation, schema, hapi.js, joi

I am defining a [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidatevalue-options-callback) schema for an object with some fields for social profiles. The goal is to ensure that all of the fields are present and that at least one of them is a non-empty string, but to allow the others to be `null`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const socialUrl = joi.string().min(1).alphanum().allow(null);
const schema = joi.object({
    facebook : socialUrl.required(),
    twitter  : socialUrl.required(),
    youtube  : socialUrl.required()
}).required()
```

This works great except that the following object is considered valid:

```
{
    facebook : null,
    twitter  : null,
    youtube  : null
}
```

Using [min()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectminlimit) and [or()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectorpeers) on the object doesn't help because the fields exist, they're just the wrong type.

It would be pretty trivial to do an extra loop myself afterwards and check for the specific case of all fields being `null`, but that is not ideal.

This is being used for [payload validation](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/validation#input) where it would be nice to know that the client understands the full schema, hence the desire that all of the fields be present. Maybe that is not worth it. I do get the sense that I could use some verbose [when()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhenref-options) code to get the job done, but it seems like at that point I might as well just make my own loop. Hoping to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 2):

here is ready answer: [Using Joi, require one of two fields to be non empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864812/using-joi-require-one-of-two-fields-to-be-non-empty)

joi has `.alternatives()` [method](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.0.1/API.md#alternativestryschemas), that has `.try()` method in which you could simply go through all the options
In each case you must keep only one `required` field

```
const socialUrl = joi.string().min(1).alphanum().allow(null);

const schema = joi.alternatives().try(
  joi.object({
    facebook: socialUrl.required(),
    twitter: socialUrl,
    youtube: socialUrl,
  }),
  joi.object({
    facebook: socialUrl,
    twitter: socialUrl.required(),
    youtube: socialUrl,
  }),
  joi.object({
    facebook: socialUrl,
    twitter: socialUrl,
    youtube: socialUrl.required(),
  }),
);
```

So, you don't need to use `.min()` or `.or()`

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping. Unfortunately, this doesn't validate that all fields are present. So objects like `{ facebook : 'foo' }` validate successfully, where I want to require the input to be `{ facebook : 'foo', twitter : null, youtube : null }` instead.

Comment: @SethHolladay
Could you give me at least one-three valid and invalid examples?

Comment: Sure! I made a repo with tests @IlnurIbat see https://github.com/sholladay/repro-so-45123536

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oxor` operator, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695534/joi-validator-only-one-of-keys) a description. It worked for my case, which I was 2 fields that can't be used at the same time, but if both of them are not used I don't want to receive any warnings as if I used `xor`...