# Joi validator only one of keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am working on an api that should allow multiple params but for three of them I would like to allow only one of them.
It easier with values for each key but I am wondering if Joi allows it too or I should add extra validation logic in my server.

In short, for keys `a`, `b` or `c` I want to fail any request that has more than one of the three, so:

1. `http://myapi.com/?a=value` is **a valid** request.
2. `http://myapi.com/?b=value&c=value2` is **invalid**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for [object.xor(peers)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectxorpeers) if exactly one of `a`, `b`, or `c` is required.

> Defines an exclusive relationship between a set of keys where one of them is required but not at the same time where:
>
> - `peers` - the exclusive key names that must not appear together but where one of them is required. `peers` can be a single string value, an array of string values, or each peer provided as an argument.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.any(),
    b: Joi.any(),
    c: Joi.any()
}).xor('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Or, [object.oxor(peers)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectoxorpeers) if only one of `a`, `b`, or `c` is allowed, but none are required.

> Defines an exclusive relationship between a set of keys where only one is allowed but none are required where:
>
> - `peers` - the exclusive key names that must not appear together but where none are required.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.any(),
    b: Joi.any(),
    c: Joi.any()
}).oxor('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I will do it with a Joi.try.

```js
const one_of_them = {
      query: Joi.alternatives().try(
        {
          a: Joi.string().required(),
          b: Joi.string().invalid().required(),
          c: Joi.string().invalid().required(),
        },
        {
          b: Joi.string().required(),
          a: Joi.string().invalid().required(),
          c: Joi.string().invalid().required(),
        },
        {
          c: Joi.string().required(),
          a: Joi.string().invalid().required(),
          b: Joi.string().invalid().required(),
        },
      ),
    };
```

But, maybe another solution can be better.